# Is it possible to use JavaScript Functions in a C# Method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview, dialog

I use 2 WebForms ans I want use one webform and from this I want open a Dialog with the second Webform. 
I want open the Dialog if I click on a LinkButton from the ListView and it works fine but I need values for the second Webform and so I first open the Dialog. This Dialog is empty. After I close this Dialog the Values send to a Session.

ASPX:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">

         function OpenChild() {

             var WinSettings = "center:yes;resizable:no;dialogHeight:550px"
             var MyArgs = window.showModalDialog("Benutzer.aspx", MyArgs, WinSettings);

         }

    </script>
...
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE" class="TableClass">
                    <th id="th1" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBenutzer" runat="server" >id_Benutzer</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th2" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkemail" runat="server" >id_Email</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th3" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVorname" runat="server" >id_Vorname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th4" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" >id_Nachname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th5" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTelefon" runat="server" >id_Telefon</asp:LinkButton></th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass">    
                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>

              <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass"> 

                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenChild()" /></td>

                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

C# Code:

...

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                //Der Index der Zeile wird ermitellt
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                //Der Inhalt (GUID[Unsichtbar]) wird aus der zeile mit dem Index herausgezogen und übergeben
                Label lb = (Label)myListView.Items[index].FindControl("Label6");

                //Der GUID, Benutzer-Nachname und das Werk werden an eine Session übergeben
                Session["UserID"] = lb.Text;
                Session["SearchUser"] = txtBenutzer.Text;
                Session["DropDownValue"] = dropWerk.SelectedValue;


                //Es wird eine neue Webform geöffnet
                Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx",true);

            }

        }
```

...

I  want that i save my Values in a Session and than open the dialog

tarasov

Comment: did you consider using asynchronous callback to the server on link click and opening the second form on response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Code is always called first before server side code..you have to think about alternate way...You can use the ItemCommand Property of List View to set the Session Value and then call the Javascript function from Codebehind to open the Popup.

```
protected void ListView_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "OpenPopup"))
    {

      ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
      Session["UserID"]=((Label)dataItem.FindControl("Label6")).Text;
      Session["SearchUser"] = txtBenutzer.Text;                     
      Session["DropDownValue"] = dropWerk.SelectedValue;
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Key", "OpenPopupFunction();", true); 

    }     

}
```

Comment: I get an Error if I use this Code..System.InvalidOperationException: The ListView "myListView" have a SelectedIndexChanging-Event execute. What is the Parameter Key?

Comment: I have written above code just to give you an idea of how to implement your required functionality via ItemCommand...pls don't copy paste blindly...you need to see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx article so that you would understand this method properly...and "RegisterStartupScript" is a way to call the Javascript Function from Code behind...you can call this to open your popup...Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx article to get more idea...

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, yes you can use javascript server-side with the ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method here's an msdn article explaining it in detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: no, my C# Code send about Sessions Values to the second Form and my javascript Code open a Dialog with the second webform. But  want first send the Values and than open the dialog with this values from the Session and I don't know how I make it